# Checking a pattern from a hashset in c# and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, hashset

I have HashSet of some patterns.

```
HashSet<string> patternList;
```

I am writing a LINQ query which is Iterating over a  List of Objects. Each element of this object has a name property.
I want to return only those elements from this list if the name matches any pattern present in the HashSet. i.e.

```
(from d in listOfObjects where d.name <matches any pattern present in patternList> select d)
```

I know I can do it using a loop outside the LINQ, but I was thinking how do I accomodate it inside LINQ.

Please let me know if the question is not clear or does not make sense.

Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Please limit linq (or sql) querries to ~1 main keyword per line. Does wonders for readability. Answer is good example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from d in listOfObjects 
where patternList.Any(p => p.Matches(d.name))
select d
```

I am not sure how you are doing your pattern matching, but I would put that inside the Any() clause.

This will run each pattern against each item in listOfObjects until the p.Matches() (or whatever you are using) returns true.

Comment: the pattern would always contain a string which should be a substring of d.name. Will your query work in that case? I was looking to use something like a indexOf here

Comment: yes it worked as per your suggestion. I put a predicate of something like this - patternList.Any(e=>d.name.indexOf(e)>=0)